# Reading apache connection timeout from PHP

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I'm having some trouble and searched for the solution in the `$_SERVER` and `$_SESSION` variables, but couldn't find it. However, in the `phpinfo()` i found `Timeouts Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 15`.

Asuming that is what i am searching for (the number of seconds of inactivity before apache closes the connection), is there any other way of reading it?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find that information? Under what heading?

Comment: I'm curious, did my answer ever work out for you?

Comment: @thirtydot: Ah, sorry for not answering, we ended in fact not needing that data. I tested your solution and it gives me '15', so it works for what i asked. However, what i asked for was not exactly what i needed, cos i'm sure the number of seconds of inactivity before apache closes the connection is 7200, 2 hours. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You should mark the best answer with a big green CHECK near them to make the responder feel happy for what he did.

Answer (score 1):

See the [`apache_response_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-response-headers.php) function, and also the accompanying comments.

This works for me:

```
<?php

flush();
$apache_headers = apache_response_headers();
//echo '<pre>' . print_r($apache_headers, true) . '</pre>';
preg_match('/timeout=(\d+)/', $apache_headers['Keep-Alive'], $matches);
echo $matches[1];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

there exist funcitons ini_get, ini_set for reading and writing php.INI values